# ListView doesn't scroll to bottom after adding item

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

The Activity contains an edit text, submit button, and a list view that gets its data from a server. When I click, the edit Text, it scrolls to the bottom as it is supposed to:

```
  editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
            scrollMyListViewToBottom();
            Log.i("yoyo","ListSize Before: " + size);
    }
});
```

However, when I click on the submit Button, and after the list view updates when `notifydatasetchanged();` is called, It does not scroll to the bottom. If you are wondering what happens in `CommentQuery();`, I can provide more code.

```
    submitComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            commentItem = new ParseObject("CommentItem");
            commentItem.put("parentUser", feedUserName);
            commentItem.put("parentFeed", feedItem);
            // commentItem.put("parentObjectId", objectId);
            commentItem.put("commentText", String.valueOf(commentText.getText()));
            commentItem.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
            commentItem.put("country", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getInt("country"));
            commentItem.put((ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername() + "globalPoints"), 0);
            commentItem.put("parentObjectId", objectId);
            replies +=1;


            commentItem.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        arrayCommentList.clear();
                        comments.clearCachedResult();
                        CommentQuery();
                    customCommentListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        Log.i("yoyo","ListSize After: " + size);   //size changes like it is supposed to

                        scrollMyListViewToBottom(); //doesn't do anything
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

scrollMyListViewToBottom() Function:

```
   public void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
    commentList.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...

            commentList.setSelection(size);
        }
    });

}
```

CommentQuery Function:

```
public void CommentQuery(){

    comments = new ParseQuery<>("CommentItem");
    comments.setLimit(99);
    comments.whereEqualTo("parentObjectId", objectId);
    comments.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> mobjects, ParseException e) {

            if(e == null){

                for(ParseObject object : mobjects){

                    parseObs = mobjects;

                     size = parseObs.getsize();

                    commentData = new HashMap<>();
                    commentData.put("username", object.getString("username"));
                    commentData.put("feed", object.getString("commentText"));
                    commentData.put("likes", String.valueOf(object.getInt("likes")));
                    commentData.put("country", String.valueOf(object.getInt("country")));
                    commentData.put("replies", String.valueOf(0));
                    commentData.put("global", String.valueOf(object.getInt(usernameText+"globalPoints")));

                    arrayCommentList.add(commentData);

                }
                customCommentListViewAdapter = new CustomCommentListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayCommentList);
                commentList.setAdapter(customCommentListViewAdapter);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You don't seem to ever increment `size`, so I would expect the scroll to remain unchanged.

Comment: If you read the log, it says `size` changes like it is supposed to. @MattClark

Comment: If you had posted the log, maybe I could have read it and known that ;)

Comment: It is posted ;) ;), It's in the `SubmitComment` Click Listener @MattClark

Comment: Code comments != logs ;)

Comment: Lesson learned.. would you perhaps have an idea of why it doesn't scroll to bottom after `notifydatasetchanged();`? After the Listview refreshes, the `scrollToBottom();` function has no effect, in fact the list view's position just remains at the top.

Comment: You should not store a hard-coded `size` variable. It does not change at the same point as `customCommentListViewAdapter.getCount()`

Comment: Also, I think `commentList.smoothScrollToPosition(customCommentListViewAdapter.getCount())` might work better, but really don't know.

Comment: I tried that method also, didn't work @cricket_007

Comment: Well, in any case, it would be useful to see a [mcve]. We can't tell what `CommentQuery()` is doing, or how the adapter is even updated.

Comment: I added `CommentQuery()` as a minimal, verifiable example, if that helps. @cricket_007

Comment: I wouldn't exactly consider that "minimal", but sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - Don't do this. `parseObs = mobjects;` whatever adapter you just set using `parseObs` just lost the reference to that list.

You instead need to do this.

```
parseObs.clear();
parseObs.addAll(mobjects);
```

---

Next, `size = parseObs.getsize();` definitely does not need to be within the loop. The list shouldn't change in size while you are iterating over it.

---

Finally, this already does what you want inside of the Parse Callback

```
customCommentListViewAdapter = new CustomCommentListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayCommentList);
commentList.setAdapter(customCommentListViewAdapter);
```

You do not need to notify the adapter again.

```
CommentQuery();
// customCommentListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Not necessary
```

Then, `CommentQuery` is *asynchronous*.

```
arrayCommentList.clear(); // List is now empty
... 
CommentQuery(); // doing stuff ... in the background
..
scrollMyListViewToBottom(); // there isn't anything to scroll to yet!
```

---

Basically, solution is to `scrollMyListViewToBottom()` within `CommentQuery()`'s `done { }` method block, which would be after the ListView contains the data.

And, as I said in the comments, `size` is not necessary as a variable. Just use `customCommentListViewAdap‌​ter.getCount()`

Comment: Putting `scrollMyListViewToBottom()` in `done { }` was what needed to be done! Also, I deleted `size` and reverted to `customCommentListViewAdap‌​ter.getCount()`. Works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear. I'm not sure what you were seeing with your comment that "size changes like it is supposed to"

Comment: the log showed me that the size of the list view incremented after the list was updated

Comment: You never updated the variable of `size` after clearing the list. If you had, then you would see it print out zero. Which is why I said the `size` variable shouldn't be used.